# Каким образом при подключении junit (к примеру) мы импортируем его с org.junit....?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, junit

Я подключил `junit.jar` к проекту в `IDEA` и потом импортирую его `import static org.junit.Assert.*`. Где лежит данная библиотека? И что значит `org`? Спасибо.

Comment: используйте систему сборки maven или gradle, не нужно руками перемещать jar архивы. org.junit название домена записанное наоборот, в  java так принято называть пакеты чтобы классы имели уникальное обозначение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как упомянули в комментарии. используйте систему сборки. это значительно упростит вашу жизнь.

Библиотеки, скорее всего, при ручном добавлении укладываются в папку "lib" или что нибудь вроде того.

Касательно "что значит org" - в джаве существуют некоторые соглашения относительно именования. Как и упоминал комментатор - пакет вида com.example.package - указывает на пакет package, который написан разработчиками example.com

подробнее можно почитать в [официальном источнике](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) oracle

Comment: Могу ли я каким-то образом увидеть подключенную библиотеку в `lib`?